# Пишу код по уроку. Пишет что "Object () не принимает параметров"

Tags: python

Когда задаю графический объект в строке `hero = Sprite(0, 0, 'h.png')`пишет что "Object() не принимает параметров". Что не так делаю?

```
import pygame

window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
pygame.display.set_caption("Hello, pygame!")

screen = pygame.Surface((400, 400))


class Sprite:
    def _init_(self, xpos, ypos, filename):
        self.x = xpos
        self.y = ypos
        self.bitmap = pygame.image.load(filename)
        self.bitmap.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))

    def render(self):
        screen.blit(self.bitmap,(self.x, self.y))

hero = Sprite(0, 0, 'h.png')
zet = Sprite(0, 0, 'z.png')
done = True

while done:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = False

    screen.fill((50, 50, 50))

    hero.render()
    zet.render()
    window.blit(screen, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.delay(5)
```

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке добавте в тело вопроса, а заголовок измените так, что-бы он в общем обозначил проблему.

Comment: В вашем уроке точно-точно написанно именно `_init_` а не что-то немножко другое?

Comment: Исправьте  `_init_` на `__init__`

Comment: Обалдеть даже не подумал бы. Спасибо. Такие маленькие на первый взгляд нюансы, а последствия глобальны. Еще раз благодарю!

Comment: @godva, опубликуйте ваш комментарий как ответ, пожалуйста - это может помочь будущим посетителям решить аналогичную проблему

Comment: @m9_psy не надо поощрять вопросы про опечатки

Answer (score 0):

Исправьте `_init_` на `__init__`, [описание](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__).